# What distortion model opencv uses for fisheye calibration?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, fisheye

Despite reading [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html#ga384940fdf04c03e362e94b6eb9b673c9) and other places online, I'm still not completely sure about the model.

A follow up question, is it possible to use a different distortion model on opencv?

I'm using 4.1.2.30 version.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: in the "Detailed Description" Chapter of this website https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html you can find the formulas of how porjection works with fisheye distortion. Undistortion should be the inverse of the last part.

Comment: This is the link I referenced to. I still not sure to what model the equations belongs to.

Comment: to the fisheye model that is implemented in opencv cv::fisheye

Comment: and yes, you can use another distortion model. See the "Detailed Description" part here in the non-fisheye cv:: part: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html

Comment: Is the opencv fisheye model is Brown-Conrady Model?